# Why the popular refrence to zombies eating brains, when it's very rare to see zombies eating brains?

Tags: movie, video-games

I was thinking, you see references to zombies eating brains constantly. Yet even in the movies/games in which they mention zombies eating brains, zombies are much more likely to eat other body parts, I don't even think I've seen a zombie eating a brain.

So why the Zombies = Eating brains thought-process? Is it metaphorical? Or did the original zombies eat brains?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=zombie+eating+brains&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-gbGB497GB497&oq=zombie+eating+brains&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3895j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=zombie+eating+brains&tbm=vid

Comment: There are many films and TV shows where zombies do eat brains. You might want to watch "Return of the Living Dead"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Return of the Living Dead (1985)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_the_Living_Dead) was the first movie that featured brain-eating zombies. Specifically the "Tarman" zombie lurches around screaming for brains - eating brains is the only way zombies can counteract the pain of rotting. In earlier movies, zombies were either generically cannibals (Night of the Living Dead) or more traditional Haitian zombies (White Zombie). RotLD performed well at the box office and is beloved by horror movie fans, which probably accounts for how ubiquitous the "zombies eat brains" trope it.